# using useRef with older version react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use useRef for component that use the old ref callback api?

```
const App = () => (
  //how to get ref of input?
  <div>
    <Input ref={r => console.log(r)} />
    <Button type="primary">Hello</Button>
  </div>
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hello-antd-p6peq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could work?

```
const App = () => {
  const myRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Input
        ref={r => {
          myRef.current = r;
        }}
      />
      <Button type="primary">Hello</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you have a `useRef`??? This is a functional component

```
const App = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  // console.log(inputRef.current) //  => <Input />
  return (
    <div>
      <Input ref={inputRef} />
      <Button type="primary">Hello</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```